# Reducing conditions within a if statement

Tags: java

I have a code snippet as below. Here there is a nested if else loop as well as multiple conditions [all different parameters]. What is the best way to optimize this.

```
    if(request!=null && !StringUtils.isBlank(request)) {
        if(request.getFirstName()!=null && !StringUtils.isBlank(request.getFirstName())
                && request.getLastName()!=null && !StringUtils.isBlank(request.getLastName())
                && request.getAge()!=null && !StringUtils.isBlank(request.getAge())
                && request.getAddress()!=null && !StringUtils.isBlank(request.getAddress())
                && request.getPhoneNumber()!=null && !StringUtils.isBlank(request.getPhoneNumber())) {
            return true;
        }else {
            return false;
        }
    }else {
        return false;
    }
```

I had thought of using switch case and for loop as well but all the conditions are based on different variables, I didn't see it as compatible.

Comment: Are you sure you want the `!!`?

Comment: it is a typo... will need only !

Answer (score 7, accepted):

StringUtils from commons-lang already has a method which accepts an array of Strings. It will check for null or empty or blank strings. So all your checks boil down to:

```
    return !(request == null || StringUtils.isAnyBlank(
             request.getFirstName, request.getLastName,
             request.getAge, request.getPhoneNumber));
```

Comment: Thanks!! wasn't aware of StringUtils.isAnyBlank()

Answer (score 0):

You can try `StringUtils.isAnyBlank()`. Please refer attached link.

isAnyBlank : https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#isAnyBlank-java.lang.CharSequence

Comment: There's no Validation framework - only Bean Validation (aka JSR 303). And it's not clear why you point to Spring's docs and not the official specs: https://beanvalidation.org/2.0/

Answer (score 0):

You have a few syntax errors

- You are passing `request` to `StringUtils` but it doesn't appear to implement `CharSequence`
- You are using `!!` instead of `!`
- You invocation of the get methods does not include the `()` to mark it as methods.

Although not an error, you do not need nested if-statements here.   Using unnecessary if-else-blocks can make it harder to decipher what the code is doing.  It can, however, allow for comments to describe why certain conditions are being checked or whatever.  None of that seems relevant here.  In fact, you can pass the result of the boolean operation without any if-statement.  Using if-statements that return true or false looks like this.

```
if (<condition-is-true?>) return true 
else return false;
```

Which can be simplified to...

```
return <condition-is-true?>;
```

Further, assuming you are using using Apache `StringUtils`, you do not need to check for null first - the `isEmpty(CharSequence)` method does that.  Additionally, `StringUtils` includes the `isAnyEmpty(CharSequence...)` method so you can pass all of the Strings at once.

```
return request != null && !StringUtils.isAnyEmpty(
      request.getFirstName(),
      request.getLastName(),
      request.getAge(),
      request.getAddress(),
      request.getPhoneNumber());
```

Comment: Both !! and () were typo... I have corrected it now.

Comment: Thanks!! StringUtils.isAnyBlank() serves the requirement.

Comment: @user16320675 you are correct - the second condition should be negated.  Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't use `commons-lang` dependency you can simply use Stream API (Java 8+)

```
Boolean allNonBlank = Stream.of(
                        request.getFirstName(),
                        request.getLastName(),
                        request.getAge(),
                        request.getPhoneNumber())
                .allMatch(it -> it != null && !String.isBlank(it));
```